# VB macro or office addin for mac

Tags: macos, ms-word, ms-office, add-in, office-addins

Currently we developed a VB macro for word. While we tried to use it on mac it failed with message "VB Macro not supported in mac".
Is there a way to c# office add-in for mac?
My requirement is to have a simple utility to add comments(read from user) to the selected text in the current word document. Also need the functionality of the OpenFileDialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mac Office does not (i.e. no longer) support COM/VBA automation. This means that you won't be able to use code from your existing Windows add-in.

In order to automate Mac Office you would have to make use of Automator Actions. I am not very familiar with these, but I believe that they are less feature-rich than the VBA object model of the Windows edition.

The following page has some Actions to get you started:

> [Microsoft Office Automator Actions](http://automatorworld.com/archives/microsoft-office-automator-actions/)

**Update**: It seems that the new Mac Office 2011 comes again with some support for VBA automation.