# Using Firemonkey to merge data with MS Word docs

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey, office-automation

I'm about to write a windows app that will merge database data with ms word docs. I would like to know whether I am able to do that with Firemonkey, so in the future I can reuse the non Windows-specific code in Mac. Am I able to use MS Office automation in Firemonkey? Thanks

Comment: Office Automation on Mac OS is different, since there is no COM. Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545725/vb-macro-or-office-addin-for-mac

Comment: So do you want to use Office automation on Mac OS and Windows or Windows only?

Comment: "Am I able to use MS Office automation in Firemonkey?" Yes. But only on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Firemonkey is just a visual framework and has no bearing on non-visual file processing etc.

The underlying language is Delphi/Pascal (or C++) and is very powerful and flexible.

I don't know what office automation involves, but I assume it is COM, which Delphi (and C++) is perfectly capable of working with.